# Bluetooth iOS Windows

Tags: ios, .net, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I recently developed an application for a client, an app iOS, Android and windows, the mobile app acts as a controller and launches certain events on the windows application. The Windows application also shares data at random (not known to the mobile app) moments. The communication was done by TCP. And works great.
The client now wants it for bluetooth. Between Android and Windows, it's not been a problem and has been done, and works well. But iOS is sadly not the same story... The use of Bluetooth low energy seems to complicate things.
I've hunted high and low on google to find anything on communication between a .net application and a Swift application, to no avail. This surprises me that no one talks of a bluetooth communication between Windows and iOS.
My question is, very simply. Is it possible? I know very little about bluetooth and I've tried researching devices and all I find is a BeeWi device that's in our office, not my computer (I maybe need to launch something on computer first? The devices are paired)
My computer has a Bluetooth 4.0 dongle and the BLE emulator is present in the Device manager.
If this isn' possible, tell me know and put me out of my misery, otherwise give me hope! 
Any additional advice is warmly welcome - Thank you all !

Beau Carrel

Answer (score 0):

Windows has support for being a BLE client. Just Google it and you'll find many examples, such as https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Samples/BLEGatt2.

You need to set up iOS to be an advertising peripheral.

Comment: Apologies for my slow reply, expected an email from stack overflow.
Thanks for your response, I recently did discover that others have done this as you say, with the iOS device as the advertising peripheral. 
I had only tried the other way around, with windows advertising and that didn't seem to work (or I was doing something wrong - which is likely)
I'll post what I can of my progression to help others